# Symfony Access ajax JSON response in separate controller method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a controller with a method/route `assistantsActionView()` that  builds two forms then renders a Twig template. Within that template I have a user action modal which at one point sends an ajax request to a separate function `handleAjax()` which returns a response, then displays info accordingly.

However, I need to access one of the objects that is sent via the JSON Response in `assistantsActionView()`. How can I go about this?

```
 public function handleUserSearchAjaxRequest(Request $request, $courseSpace)
    {
     // handle the ajax, return response
     $outputData = [
            'output' => $errorCount . ' other assistants will not be added',
            'notFoundOutput' => ' were not found in the directory:',
            'notFoundUsers' => $notFoundUsers,
            'existingOutput' => ' already have access to this course space:',
            'existingUsers' => $existingAssistants,
            'validUsers' => $validUsers, // ** This is the data I need to access in the dB**
            'valid' => $isValid,
            'maxAssistantsOutput' => $maxAssistantsOutput,
            'maxUsers' => $maxUsers,
            'extraUsersCount' => $extraUsersCount
        ];
        return new JsonResponse($outputData);

    }

// The controller

 public function assistantEnrollmentAction(Request $request, ListSettings $listSettings, CourseSpace $courseSpace)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(AddAssistantType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $bulkAddForm = $this->createForm(UserBulkAddType::class);
        $bulkAddForm->handleRequest($request);

       // Handle forms and stuff
         if ($bulkAddForm->isSubmitted() &&  $bulkAddForm->isValid()) {
          // here I need to access the validUsers data sent in the JSON response

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you want to send the jSON to the second function, so in this case can call the second function and send the data like this:

```
public function a() {
   self::b($yourJsonData); // here you send your json data to the other function
}

public function b($jsonData) {
   // Do what you want to do with the received jSON data 
}
```

Comment: what if method b already gets called due to the route being directed to? So for example:
user goes to route -> `b()` is called -> user performs action -> ajax request send to `a()` -> response is sent to jquery -> user continues with form process -> submits form which is handled by `b()`

Comment: In this case why would you send data to b()? why can't you just do what you have to do in a() and send a jsonResponse back to jquery on your twig:  

B() -> render Twig template, 
Template/jQuery -> Send data/Ajax to A(), 
A() -> Send back a serialized response to jquery/template